# Can not find USB stick after attach it to VM

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, qemu, kvm

Am an amateur debian11 user (In contrast to an expert :-). My pc installed Debian 11 KVM/QEMU. Under Virt-Manager, VM connect to host USB successfully with the option == redirect USB device.

Need to use cli to connect host USB. So I create an XML file with the following contents, saved it as `usb.xml`:

```
<hostdev mode='subsystem' type='usb' managed='yes'>
   <source>
    <vendor id='0x1038'/>
    <product id='0x12ad'/>
  </source>
</hostdev>
```

Now attach it using `virsh` by using:

```
virsh attach-device --file usb.xml --current
```

The transfer of host USB to VM seems okay as the USB stick disappeared from host machine, and on the client in `dmesg` I see these messages:

```
New usb device found
usb hub found
2 ports detected
set hub depth failed
```

However I can not find USB stick attached to guest VM while using VM terminal. Any suggestion/guidance is appreciated.

Comment: I assume you left out the `domain` for some reason

Comment: My mistake should be virsh attach-device debian11 --file usb.xml --current

Comment: anything in `dmesg` or any other logs in the guest?

Comment: debian11 is created via Virt-Manager. Not sure how to copy text from VM to host. However dmesg showed = New usb device found = usb hub found = 2 ports detected = set hub depth failed ==== Wonder these are enough to present the situation. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, when you said `USB stick` I assumed it was a thumb drive = I've never tried a Bluetooth device (not saying that's the issue though, since 1038:12ad is apparently natively supported in linux since forever)

Answer (score 1):

The correct steps are

1. insert usb to host
2. `lsusb` to find out vendor and product ID
3. create the `usb.xml`
4. `virsh attach-device vm name --file path to usb.xml --current`

I did not do the step 1 so it failed with incorrect vendor and product ID. I hope this solution will help the new users; thank you to those who offered advice and direction.